# How to connect multiple VPN instances?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, iptables

I have multiple VPN instances on one server, each with different internal ips. I have two OpenVPN instances, and I would like for clients on each to be able to communicate with clients from each other. Here are my OpenVPN configs:

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun0
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
topology subnet
server 10.10.0.0 255.255.255.0
server-ipv6 fde6:7c9e:7ab4:0cc0::/64
cipher AES-256-GCM
auth SHA512
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt 0
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384
reneg-bytes 32000000
compress lz4-v2
push "compress lz4-v2"
push "redirect-gateway"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/crl.pem
duplicate-cn
client-to-client
topology subnet
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
```

and

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun0
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
server-ipv6 fd7d:89e2:ccd5:09ef::/64
cipher AES-256-GCM
auth SHA512
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt 0
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384
reneg-bytes 32000000
compress lz4-v2
push "compress lz4-v2"
push "redirect-gateway"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/crl.pem
duplicate-cn
client-to-client
topology subnet
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
```

And here's the only iptables rules I added for the VPN:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/24 -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: They are on entirely separate subnets...

Comment: So this isn't possible? And if not, how do I configure OpenVPN to use the same subnet?

Comment: It's certainly possible, and if you have multiple VPN servers they _should_ use separate subnets. (Though I'm not sure why you have multiple on the same machine...)

Comment: Then how do I do it? I have multiple instances because I need OpenVPN on port UDP 53 and TCP 443

Comment: What's the rest of your network topology look like? You can do this with a vlan capable switch and router. I'm not sure if you can bridge the virtual IP space, or if it would even be a good idea to do so.

Comment: I suck at networking. I use a VPS and that's pretty much all I know about networking :) (I know iptables, and basics but that's it)